# Search and replace script on a given portion of text

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I'm manipulating text files and need to build a perl script to run a search replace only on the notes of a given portion of text (chapters in this case), so that I can convert this pattern:

```
Chapter 1:1 text here(Note a) more text here(Note b)
2 text here(Note c) more text here(Note d)
3 text here(Note e) more text here(Note f)
4 text here(Note g) more text here(Note h)
Chapter 2:1 text here(Note i) more text here(Note j)
2 text here(Note k) more text here(Note l)
3 text here(Note m) more text here(Note n)
4 text here(Note o) more text here(Note p)
5 text here(Note q) more text here(Note r)
6 text here(Note s) more text here(Note t)
```

into this:

```
Chapter 1:1 text here(Note a) more text here(Note b)
2 text here(Note c) more text here(Note d)
3 text here(Note e) more text here(Note f)
4 text here(Note g) more text here(Note h)
Chapter 2:1 text here(Note a) more text here(Note b)
2 text here(Note c) more text here(Note d)
3 text here(Note e) more text here(Note f)
4 text here(Note g) more text here(Note h)
5 text here(Note i) more text here(Note j)
6 text here(Note k) more text here(Note l)
```

In other words, I need to set the 'counter' of each note to "a" at the start of each new chapter. The following regex matches every chapter:

```
(?s)^\w{1,10} \d{1,3}:\d{1,3}.+?\(Note \w\).+?(?=\w{1,10} \d{1,3}:\d{1,3})
```

and I have tried to use a while loop like this:

```
my @notes = ('Note a', 'Note b', 'Note c', 'Note d');
$Count = a;
foreach my $Marker (@notes) {
    $_=~s/(\\(Note\\))[a-z]/"$1".$Count++/e;
}
```

But I am stuck and cannot possibly think of a way to build a script in such a way that it stops at every chapter division and then starts again until the end. Maybe I'm using the wrong approach?

What do I need to do in order to apply the search and replace only to each chapter, as shown above (i.e., the first regex)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT (July 30)**

Both answers work fine. I voted the first one as my favorite because I understand the logic better, but BOTH are equally valid.

Now, as a corollary to my first question. How could I easily include the chapter name and chapter number **sequentially** before each line? Like this:

```
Chapter 1:1 text here(Note a) more text here(Note b)
Chapter 1:2 text here(Note c) more text here(Note d)
Chapter 1:3 text here(Note e) more text here(Note f)
Chapter 1:4 text here(Note g) more text here(Note h)
Chapter 2:1 text here(Note a) more text here(Note b)
Chapter 2:2 text here(Note c) more text here(Note d)
Chapter 2:3 text here(Note e) more text here(Note f)
Chapter 2:4 text here(Note g) more text here(Note h)
Chapter 2:5 text here(Note i) more text here(Note j)
Chapter 2:6 text here(Note k) more text here(Note l)
```

Do I need to use a variable and increment it or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: You do not need to add `<br>` tags when posting your question, just press enter to make newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it without splitting, like this:

```
s/^(chapter\s+\d+:\d+)|(\(note\s+)[a-z]+(?=\))/$a='a'if$1; $1?$1:$2.$a++/gime;
```

PS: Don't forget to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

---

Full example based on OPs comment:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', '/Users/rgp/Desktop/Test.txt' or die "cant open file: $!";
my $content = do { local $/ = undef; <$fh> };
close $fh;

$content =~ s/^(chapter\s+\d+:\d+)|(\(note\s+)[a-z]+(?=\))/$a='a'if$1; $1?$1:$2.$a++/gime;

print "Result:\n";
print $content;
```

Comment: using your code in Mac OS X (BBEdit) doesn't seem to work for me. Am I missing something?. Here is the full script: open(Input, '+</Users/rgp/Desktop/Test.txt') || die "No such file found!"; use strict; use warnings; while(<Input>) { $_=~s/^(chapter\s+\d+:\d+)|((note\s+)[a-z]+(?=))/$a='a'if$1; $1?$1:$2.$a++/gime; print $_; }

Comment: This regex works on the whole file at once, I've updated the answer to show you how it could be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the trouble to answer. The problem I'm finding with this script is that it only changes Chapter 1, but leaves all the notes in Chapter 2 and following untouched. My original question was about automating the whole process, since I work with very large files with hundreds of chapters.

Comment: It works for all chapters, at least on your sample data. See the demonstration at: http://ideone.com/pJaag

Comment: You are absolutely right. I took a section of an actual document (as per your demonstration example) and it worked! But for the life of me I can't make your full example above work. As I said before, I am using BBEdit. I am running the script (Western Mac OS Roman and Unix LF) on a Western Mac OS Roman and Classic Mac CR file (i.e., Test.txt). What on earth is wrong?

Comment: Okay, if I change the input file to Unix (LF) instead of Classic Mac (CR), the script works as expected. Great!

Comment: Could your script be adapted to meet the additional requirement I explained (see edition) or would I need a different one altogether? Thanks!

Comment: This code would obviously work if I wanted to prepend every single line simply with "Chapter 1:"    $content =~ s/^(Chapter\s+\d+:\d+)|(\d+\s+)/$a='1'if$1; $1?$1:"Chapter" . " " . "$a" . ":" . $2/gime;
but I need to change the number at the beginning of each new chapter.

Comment: `s/^(?:\s*chapter\s+(\d+):)?/$a=$1?$1:$a; "Chapter $a:"/gime` http://ideone.com/GTMLq

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you ever so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You should split your text into chapters and process those individually.

```
# $book holds your text
my @chapters = split /^(?=Chapter\s+\d+:\d+)/m, $book;

for my $chap (@chapters) {
    my $cnt = 'a';
    $chap =~ s/(?<=\(Note )[a-z]/$cnt++/ge;
    print $chap;
}
```

This will work for your example. You just need to figure out how to handle more than 26 notes (a-z).

EDIT: This is how you can read in your text line by line and write an output file:

```
open IN, 'infile.txt';
open OUT, '>', 'outfile.txt';

my $cnt;
for my $line (<IN>) {
    $cnt = 'a' if $line =~ /^Chapter\s+\d+:\d+/;
    $line =~ s/(?<=\(Note )[a-z]/$cnt++/ge;
    print OUT $line;
}
```

Comment: 'z' will increase to 'aa' when using the inc operator. Perl magic.

Comment: @mhyfritz, yes, that's right, although I don't think there are that many notes in any of the chapters. However, I can't find out if the code works. I work with set IO files and then print the Output file (or simply $_). For example: open(Input, '+</Users/rgp/Desktop/Test.txt') || die "No such file found!"; while(<Input>) { YOUR CODE HERE; print $_; How do I print the result to my output file (or BBEdit's Unix Script Output file)? Thanks!

Comment: You may simply use shell redirection to print the file. I.e. `script.pl > output.txt`.

Comment: @TLP I was hoping to do it from within the perl script itself. Can this be done? If so, how? Sorry, it's 2 AM and can't think clearly...

Comment: `open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;` outside the loop, and change the print to `print $out $chap`.

Comment: @TLP Sorry, but I am getting a blank output.txt

Comment: @RGP: If I understand you correctly you a) want to read in the text line by line from a file b) output to a file. I have added some code that does both, check if it works for you.

Comment: @mhyfritz It works, thank you! As I said below in my last comment to the other person who answered, the problem was that the input file had to be set to Unix (LF) instead of Classic Mac (CR).

Comment: You've all been very helpful, and I appreciate you sharing your time and experience. Great site indeed!